# Dynamically generate one value in a Django include tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have an include tag that works fine if I hard code the values, but I need to generate on the fly using `{{ foo_counter }}`.  Doing it this way:

```
{% include "template.html" with foo=var1 pos="var_num_{{foo_counter.next}}" bool="0" %}
```

just outputs the string as is without interpreting the variable (as I would expect).  I've tried some combinations of the with tag around it but I either get a Template Error or the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Django's inbuilt `add` filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#add

`{% include "template.html" with foo=var1 pos="var_num_"|add:foo_counter.next bool="0" %}`

Comment: Wow.  Could not be simpler!  Thanks!